# Expand the function $e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ in laurent series around the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Expand the function $e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ in laurent series around the origin and show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)d\theta=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!(n+k)!} \quad (n \ge 0)$$

I am attempting to expand $e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ and trying to force it to be $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)d\theta$ but I am not seeing how I get from the first to the second

Comment: Write the function as $e^z e^{1 \over z}$ in order to compute the Laurent expansion. You need to compute $a_{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. @copper.hat